# Get data from 2 Model in Django python

Tags: python, django, orm, django-rest-framework, models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    avgrating = models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Rating(models.Model):
    Product_id = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='Product_id')
    User_id = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='User_id')
    rate = models.IntegerField()
```

I want like 
- name of the product
- price of the product
- avgrating (AVG rating)
- depend on User_id and Product_id and

SQL query like:

```
select p.name,p.price,p.avgrating,r.rate from Product p, Rating r where User_id=1;
```

out Like:

in json formate

```
{
  "name":"Iphone 8",
  "Price":80000,
  "avgrating":3.5,
  "rate":5
}
```

Comment: Show us what you tried so far? There are a lot of example in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
results = Rating.objects.filter(User_id_id = 1)
data = []
for res in results:
    data.append( {
          "name": res.Product_id.name,
          "Price": res.Product_id.price,
          "avgrating": res.Product_id.avgrating,
          "rate": res.rate
    })
```

Why did i use User_id_id?

Beacuse, Django appends '_id' for all names related to keys. So if you are using the key value directly, use '_id'.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.filter(User_id__id=1)`?

Comment: @dm295 no.. it's just User_id_id